# Trying to get single-spa working with angularjs v1.3.7

Tags: angularjs, single-spa

I have my old frontend written in angularjs v1.3.7. I am trying to get it working with single-spa, I followed the guide in the docs, but I am still getting "legacyAngularApp status NOT_LOADED" without getting any other errors. Could this be because I use an older angularjs version?

the code in my index.html:

```
  <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.1/lib/system/single-spa.min.js",
        "@app/legacyAngularApp": "./js/config.js",
        "@app/reactApp": "//localhost:8080/reactApp.js"
      }
    }
  </script>

/*dependecies*/

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import("single-spa").then(function (singleSpa) {
        window.singleSpa = singleSpa;
        window.singleSpa.registerApplication({
          name: "legacyAngularApp",
          app: () => System.import("@app/legacyAngularApp"),
          activeWhen: ["#/dashboards/single-spa"],
        });
        window.singleSpa.registerApplication({
          name: "reactApp",
          app: () => System.import("@app/reactApp"),
          activeWhen: ["#/dashboards/react-app"],
        });
        window.singleSpa.start();
      });
    </script>
```

the code in my config.js:

```
System.register([], function (_export) {
    return {
      execute: function () {
        _export(
          window.singleSpaAngularjs.default({
            angular: angular,
            mainAngularModule: "inspinia",
            uiRouter: true,
            preserveGlobal: false,
          })
        );
      },
    };
  });
```

and in the controller:

```
var extraControllers = angular.module("inspinia");

extraControllers.controller("singleSPASwitchCtrl", [
  "$scope",
  "$state",

  function ($scope, $state) {
    console.log(
      "legacyAngularApp status",
      singleSpa.getAppStatus("legacyAngularApp")
    );
    
  },
]);
```

When I try to run the app I am getting "legacyAngularApp status NOT_LOADED" without any error messages.

Comment: You'll need to show code.  We're not (yet) magicians: :-)  Post the calls to `registerApplication()` and the lifecycle functions.

Comment: Hello!  I stopped by just checking, but next time, comment after editing and mention me to get a notification in my inbox.  First and foremost, "status NOT LOADED" is not an error condition.  It just means the `activeWhen` activity function hasn't determined that the micro-frontend needs to load.  Test around different forms of the URL in the `activeWhen` property.

Comment: Yes, thanks @JoséRamírez, the problem was with the URL specified in `activeWhen` property after I changed it it worked just fine.